# Adding Multiple Chart Series in Quantmod R

Tags: r, charts, finance, quantmod, quantitative-finance

I am trying to plot two charts on one `chartSeries` in quantmod in R. I am having some difficulty doing this.

```
library(quantmod)    
tickers <- c('GLD', 'GDX')
data <- new.env()
getSymbols(tickers, src = 'yahoo', from = '1980-01-01', env = data)
chartSeries(Cl(data$GLD), TA="addTA(Cl(data$GDX), on=1)")
addRSI()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `chart_Series` instead of `chartSeries`.

```
chart_Series(Cl(data$GLD))
add_TA(Cl(data$GDX), on = 1)
```

And then if you want RSI below in a sub panel, just add `add_RSI()`.

Another approach is to use version  >= 0.10.0 of `xts` (i.e. don't use `quantmod` at all), which you can get from https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts   (0.10.0 is not yet on CRAN).  The new `plot` function in `xts` is very friendly with plotting multiple columns of an `xts` object all at once.  Check out `?plot.xts` for examples of new functionality.

Edit #2:

To see relative changes more easily, you can normalise your price series in many ways.  This is a typical approach (using a 0 origin is what Google charts does):

```
normalise_series <- function(xdat) xdat / coredata(xdat)[1]
getSymbols("USO")
window <- "2013/"

# Define colour of default chart line to chart_Series in mytheme object
# which is passed to chart_Series:
mytheme <- chart_theme()
mytheme$col$line.col <- "darkgreen"
chart_Series(normalise_series(Cl(data$GLD)[window]) - 1, theme = mytheme)
add_TA(normalise_series(Cl(data$GDX)[window]) - 1, on = 1, col = "red", lty = 3)
add_TA(normalise_series(Cl(USO)[window]) - 1, on = 1, col = "blue", lty =2)

add_TA(RSI(Cl(data$GLD)), on = NA, col = "darkgreen")
add_TA(RSI(Cl(data$GDX)), on = 2, col = "red", lty = 3)
# Or add RSIs on different subpanels to improve readability of charts:
add_TA(RSI(Cl(USO)), on = NA, col = "blue", lty = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to normalize the graph? So it is not on absolute price data but scaled to compare the charts

Comment: Scaled in what sense? On the main chart?  You could divide the security prices by the initial price level so they both start at 1 (say) before plotting?

Comment: Scaled by percentage gained similar to Google chart that can overlay different stocks. I wanted to add rsi paths too so I can see the trends.

Comment: See second edit above.  This is exactly what my first comment suggests, and seems to be what google does too. This answers your question + adds a few extra features (Formating) you might find useful in using chart_Series functionality.