# Plot all columns (number is not predefined) of xts object on one chart

Tags: r, plot, xts

How can I write R code that will take all columns from a single xts object and plot them on a single chart?

My xts object looks like screenshot below and I don't know while writing a code what will be the number of columns there: [screenshot of xts object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6uuj.jpg)

I want R to take each of the columns and plot them as one of the lines on a single chart. Ideally, it should be some fancy quantmod charts (as each of columns is a price for a particular investment instrument) but even simple plot will be okay.

Additional comments.

Here is a datafile I use (csv): [One Drive sharepoint link to zip file](https://inseadedu-my.sharepoint.com/personal/egor_gazarov_insead_edu/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=0969b375ff1bb4cc4988a7c3e3a4915f3&authkey=AYjP6tLBVuhTdFyKwjpYgZ4&expiration=2018-02-27T21%3A00%3A00.000Z&e=TSPFse)

And this is the code I have so far:

```
etfs_history_input <- read.zoo(file = "etfs_history.csv", sep = ",", index.column = 1, header = TRUE, FUN=as.POSIXct, tz = "Europe/Moscow", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
etfs_h <- as.xts(coredata(etfs_history_input), order.by = index(etfs_history_input))
```

The closest thing I managed to achieve in meeting my target output is writing this:

```
apply(etfs_h, 2, plot)
```

But result:

- plots different instruments on different charts
- doesn't show the instrument names (column titles)

Comment: May we see whatever code you have at present? You will find you are much more likely to get help if you make a start on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `?plot.xts` if you'd like to plot using `xts`.
Example:

```
library(quantmod)
syms <- c("AAPL","MSFT", "NQ", "SSRM")
getSymbols(syms)

x <- lapply(syms, function(x) Cl(get(x)))
m <- do.call(cbind, x)

plot(m, main = "stocks")
addLegend("topleft", on=1, 
          legend.names = colnames(m), lty = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to chart using quantmod as another alternative, doing something like this might be helpful  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136008/adding-multiple-chart-series-in-quantmod-r/38136305#38136305

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like melting and then plotting with ggplot

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
d <- melt(object, measures.var = patterns("^FX"))
ggplot(d, aes(date,value, col=variable)) + 
  geom_point()
```

but without an example to test that is just a blind try

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried this (with changing "object" to my xts object name. It doesn't work, unfortunately: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found. Was I supposed to change "variable" to smth else as well?